# Перевод пары строчек кода с jQury в JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите грамотно перевести код с jQuery в JS.
popup-one__center - это select с формы
так же есть записанный дата атрибут для каждого option data-mail
значение этого атрибута при выборе option записывается в скрытый input.
не могу перевести в js
помогите пожалуйста

```
$("#popup-one__center")
.change(function () {
  $("#set_mail").val($(this).find(":selected").data("mail"));
})
.change();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const select = document.getElementById('popup-one__center');

const changeHandler = ()=>{
    let setMail = document.getElementById('set_mail');
    let mail = select ? select.selectedOptions[0].dataset.mail : undefined;
    if( setMail ) setMail.value = mail;
};

if( select ) select.addEventListener( 'change', changeHandler );

changeHandler();
```

```html
<select id="popup-one__center">
  <option data-mail="111">111</option>
  <option data-mail="222">222</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="set_mail">
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое